# Are there any open source Software as a Service projects?

Tags: software, floss

According to [this page](http://www.cio.com/article/2378859/open-source-tools/7-reasons-not-to-use-open-source-software.html)

> Cloud software is slightly different than conventional software. As a general rule, you don't get access to the source code, even if the hosted software is built entirely on open source software. That may not make the software proprietary, strictly speaking, but it doesn't give you all the benefits of open source. In that sense, the benefits of using the "pay for what you use" software as a service model may outweigh the disadvantage of not having access to the source code.

Now [OpenStack](https://www.openstack.org/) is bringing cloud support to the open source community, but what about *Software as a Service*?

Are there any open source SaaS projects out there? Does SaaS even make sense in a FLOSS context?

Comment: Are you talking about the countless companies which offer open source databases as a service, like AWS, Heroku etc.?

Comment: Possibly, but also consider the direction Microsoft is taking with Office and Adobe with its photography software

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

In short there are many many open source SaaS projects out there.

Some of these include:

- owncloud
- openshift

For a list of over 60 examples go here: [list](http://datamation.com/open-source/60-open-source-apps-you-can-use-in-the-cloud-1.html)

These products have become popular because most are free, and easy to use.